# WP7 - Generating tile image - cannot include my own image

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, tile

I am generating an image and using this as the image for a live time so that I can provide more information and have more control over how it looks. 
The issue is that whilst I am generating the image okay, its not including my own background image in it.

The following code works and picks up the image  fine

```cs
ShellTile defaultTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
defaultTile.Update(new StandardTileData
{
    Title = item2.NextDateTime.ToShortTimeString(),
    BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("Images/Tiles/tilebacking.png", UriKind.Relative),
    BackTitle = item2.NextDateTime.ToShortTimeString(),
    BackContent = item2.Details
});
```

Yet the following code, whilst generating an image is not including my initial image(as per the Var logo).
I found the code to do this on the web, and it seems to work fine except for including my initial background image.

```cs
var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(173, 173);
var logo = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/Tiles/tilebacking.png", UriKind.Relative));
var img = new Image { Source = logo };

// Force the bitmapimage to load it's properties so the transform will work
logo.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
var bl = new TextBlock();
bl.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
bl.FontSize = 24.0;
bl.Text = "any text we want!";

bmp.Render(bl, null);

var tt = new TranslateTransform();
tt.X = 173 - logo.PixelWidth;
tt.Y = 173 - logo.PixelHeight;

bmp.Render(img, tt);

bmp.Invalidate();
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    var filename = "/Shared/ShellContent/testtile.jpg";
    using (var st = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, store))
    {
        bmp.SaveJpeg(st, 173, 173, 0, 100);
    }
}


ShellTile defaultTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();

defaultTile.Update(new StandardTileData
{
    Title = item2.NextDateTime.ToShortTimeString(),
    BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/testtile.jpg", UriKind.Absolute),
    BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/testtile.jpg", UriKind.Absolute),
    BackTitle = item2.NextDateTime.ToShortTimeString(),
    BackContent = item2.Details
});
```

Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong here.  It's the same file and the same file path that works fine in the first example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [BitmapImage.ImageOpened](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.imageopened%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event to ensure it draws correctly.

This means you should write your code like this:

```cs
var logo = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/Tiles/tilebacking.png", UriKind.Relative));
logo.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
logo.ImageOpened += (sender, e) =>
{
    var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(173, 173);

    var bl = new TextBlock();
    bl.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    bl.FontSize = 24.0;
    bl.Text = "any text we want!";

    bmp.Render(bl, null);

    var tt = new TranslateTransform();
    tt.X = 173 - logo.PixelWidth;
    tt.Y = 173 - logo.PixelHeight;

    bmp.Render(img, tt);

    bmp.Invalidate();

    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        var filename = "/Shared/ShellContent/testtile.jpg";
        using (var st = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, store))
        {
            bmp.SaveJpeg(st, 173, 173, 0, 100);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

I've written a guide on the subject: [How To: Generate a custom live tile directly on the phone.](http://windcape.posterous.com/how-to-generate-a-custom-live-tile-directly-o)

Comment: Claus - thanks so much.  I did find your project that you mention here (via the WindowsPhoneGeek site) and downloaded it late last night - and hoped that it wopuld provide the answer for me.

Comment: This solution works with local image, but can I use the image from isolated storage? I change first line to following code, and it doesn't work: `var logo = new BitmapImage(new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/abc.jpg"));`

Comment: You need to explicit set the URI to be `Relative`.